# redirect to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some rewrite rules in my .htaccess that switches the domain to https if its a secure area.
I want it to switch back to http if its not a secure area, heres my rules:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/checkout(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^account(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/account$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^shop/checkout(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/shop/checkout$1 [R,L]

# Route all traffic to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_args=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the first 3 lines are uncommented as it resulting in a redirect loop.
any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It results in a redirect loop because your `RewriteCond` pair will always evaluate to `true`. You first want to check that you're actually on the SSL port, then you want to make sure that the request doesn't match your secure paths.

Your three commented-out lines should therefore be changed to this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/checkout(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1
```

**Edit:** Apparently you do actually need the explicit `[R,L]` on that redirect. Additionally, `mod_rewrite` performs an internal redirection of the URL `/index.php`, which doesn't match the secure paths checked for by the `RewriteCond`s, so the rewritten rule gets re-rewritten back to the http domain. The following should resolve both of these issues, albeit in a somewhat non-foolproof way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/checkout(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(shop/checkout|account)(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?_args=$1 [QSA]
```

People could still theoretically come in unsecured via `http://www.domain.com/index.php?_args=account` this way, so if that bothers you it's possible to write some more complex `RewriteCond` directives to handle that situation. It's a bit overkill though if you aren't worried about that. Unfortunately there's no good way that I'm aware of to know that an internal rewrite was performed, otherwise this would be much easier to account for.

Comment: This didn't work for me, i get a redirect loop when moving to https
also i assume you meant port 443

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Also, the `REQUEST_URI` starts with a forward slash, which may have been preventing the `RewriteCond` from matching correctly, hopefully that should work now.

Comment: still not working, i;ve edited my rules in my original question, any help appreciated

Comment: Alright, let's try this again. I setup a test scenario this time, so I've confirmed it does work on my end, at least.